# Clean URLs Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, clean-urls

Drupal newbie here!

So I enabled Clean URLs by checking the box for enabling clean URLs under the configuration. Ir works, as in there's no 'q=' and '?' in the URL but when I create a node the URL for it is given as example.com/node/x where x is a number.

How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noted, [clean URLs](https://drupal.org/node/15365) work for you.

You are probably looking for a way to *change* the URL path of a node.

Drupal comes with the [**Path** module](https://drupal.org/documentation/modules/path). Enable it and you’ll be able to provide an alternative URL in the node edit form.

For further functionality: [**Pathauto**](https://drupal.org/project/pathauto) is one of the most popular Drupal modules. It allows to automate the creation of those URLs.

Comment: Thank you so much, I looked at the list of modules in my localhost Drupal installation, and realized it had the Pathauto module like you suggested, and my Bluehost Drupal installation hasn't, so I installed it and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @unknownDude: You may also be interested in the [**Global Redirect** module](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) (resp. the [**Redirect** module](https://drupal.org/project/redirect)), which always redirects to the current alias (e.g., when someone visits the node via `/node/1`, or when you’ve changed the alias).